# How can import local server's website to Gitlab?

Tags: web, server, gitlab, web-deployment, localserver

I'm starter of Gitlab so I have some questions. I was searching to find something to start with but I couldn't find.
So, I have a website running on a local server 192.168.xx.xx/xxxx and I want to import it into the Gitlab account so I can watch the development of this sites of my colleagues. How could I begin? Gitlab pages work for this type of thing I want to do? Or is there any way of how could handle it? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Usually, it's as simple as "use git"

Comment: How the local server will communicate with the gitlab? The website is on 192.168.10.xx/xxxx and the gitlab is on 192.168.20.xx . (The ip its just an example). How these will communicate each other?

Comment: What do you mean by "communicate"? Gitlab is just a frontend (and some more stuff) for your git operations - it will not do anything for you if you don't commit and push your stuff

Comment: From what I understand you would like to use gitlab as your hosting provider for your personal website. I'm unsure this is the right tool to do this.

Comment: I would like to have a repository of the website. Now I want to connect Gitlab with the vsCode so i can transform the code from there and then push it in gitlab and after that push it in the other local server. Something like middle stage.